# MySQL connector with Python: getting data by field name

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have to retrieve data from a database. Right now i am using the following code:

```
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(user, password, host, database)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(*Query*)
data = cursor.fetchall()
name = data[0][0]
surname = data[0][1]
```

I would need to access the data by field name instead of raw indexes. For instance something like that

```
name = data[0]['name']
surname = data[0]['surname']
```

Thanks

Comment: try `cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)` in python 3

Comment: i am running python 2.7

Comment: @Gidx88 what is the version of your connector package? According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-cursor.html) `dictionary` is available since Connector/Python 2.0.0. Apparently not restricted to Python 3

Comment: I think dictionary is actually working but for some reasons i won't find my key. This is the code print("Countries in Europe:")
`for row in cursor:
    print("* {mykey}".format(Name=row['mykey']))`,  i have a column named "mykey" but i get a Keyerror: 'mykey'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use [MySQLdb](http://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html). Then you can change:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

To:

```
cursor = connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

and access the values by field names instead indexes.

Comment: Can't get to import the MySqlDB module

Comment: @Gidx88 follow the instructions here: https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/INSTALL

Answer (score 2):

According to [mysql-connector-python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-column-names.html) documentation, there are two ways to achieve this.

Manually:

```py
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(...)
row = dict(zip(cursor.column_names, cursor.fetchone()))
```

With `MySQLCursorDict` class:

```py
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
```